# Is there an official name for Java 7's combined / multi-catch block?

Tags: java, naming, multi-catch

Upon discussing the multiple-catch / combined catch block [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113942/1247781) with ambiguity between the terms "multiple catch block," meaning the Java 7 feature:

```
try { .. } catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB ex) { .. }
```

and "multiple catch blocks," meaning literally, multiple catch blocks:

```
} catch (ExceptionA exa) { ..
} catch (ExceptionB exb) { .. }
```

I've researched to see if the Java 7 feature has a specific, official name that can be used to clearly distinguish it from the older style of catching multiple exceptions. However, [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html) [sources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) don't seem to name this feature anywhere, while some other sources (like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/r3_8/Java7news/whats-new-java-7.html) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/multi-catch/info)) call it a "multi-catch" block.

Is there an official, Oracle-given name for this feature anywhere?

Comment: Netbeans also seems to use "multicatch"

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA [seems to use "multi-catch" as well](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/02/announcing-intellij-idea-105-with-full-java-7-support/).

Comment: As others above, this isn't "official" but [the complete reference](http://www.amazon.com/Java-The-Complete-Reference-Series/dp/0071808558) says "The second new feature is called *multi-catch*..."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification section 14.20](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20) refers to *uni-catch* and *multi-catch* clauses, which is about as official as it gets.

> A catch clause whose exception parameter is denoted as a single class type is called a *uni-catch* clause.
>
> A catch clause whose exception parameter is denoted as a union of types is called a *multi-catch* clause.

Of course, prior to Java 7 there were no multi-catch clauses, so the term "uni-catch" was never necessary until multi-catch was introduced.

The term *multi-catch* is distinct from having more than one (several, multiple) catch clauses.